# I have run into an error while installing composer-setup.exe. It says bool_false on line 1030 of php.ini file

Tags: php, composer-php

The error is definitely not on line 1030 at it is commented out. I don't know where to look for the problem. Following is the error:

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
>   D:\xampp\php\php.exe

Program Output:

> PHP:  syntax error, unexpected BOOL_FALSE in D:\xampp\php\php.ini on line 1030

I opened shell from xampp and typed PHP enter and the same error showed up. Since I am so new I have tried commenting out the previous 15 actual lines in php.ini one at a time with no luck.

Can someone give me some direction to take to eliminate this error or give me step by step instructions on how to install composer without using the composer-setup.exe? My os is windows 7 pro. I am taking a PHP class online and they are using composer so I really need to get this installed to follow the class.

Comment: I have my php.ini file available with commneted lines removed, if this might be of any help.

Comment: There is a manual installation for composer as well. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation here is also a great video walkthrough as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZocYVPP3nQY. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and continue to have same error during installation. Any suggestions on finding the error in php.ini file so that composer will install.

Comment: Honestly it seems like a issue with your xampp install. Could you try wamp and see if the same issue persists?